# Why study Galois Representations?

Tags: math-history, galois-representations

In Mathematics, often a theory becomes popular because it tells us something new or gives different proof for already established facts. For example, I have read that algebraic number theory is helpful because it helped us to solve some diaphontine equations (most notably, Fermat's last theorem).

I want to know what kind of questions are answered by Galois Representations.

Comment: See [this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/103846/why-are-galois-representations-so-important-in-number-theory).